# Extra text below listing with name "keywordstyle keywordstyle"

Tags: pdftex, tcblisting

I have defined the following listing for Python Code:

```
\newtcblisting[use counter from=sqlCode, list inside=codes]{pythonCode}[2][]{%
  listing only,
  breakable,
  top=0.25pt,
  bottom=0.25pt,
  right=0.25pt,
  left=0.25pt,
  colback=gray!15!white,
  colframe=gray!50,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  bottomrule=0pt,
  toprule=1.5pt,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  listing options={ %
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    moredelim={[is][keywordstyle]{@}{@}},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{darkgray},
    breaklines=false,
    breakautoindent=false,
    breakindent=0pt,
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    aboveskip=0pt,
    showtabs=false,
    belowskip=0pt,
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color
    escapechar=¤,
    escapeinside={\¤}{)}
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
    stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     % string literal style
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},    % comment style
  },%
  lefttitle=0pt,
  coltitle=black,
  colbacktitle=white,
  title={Listing \thetcbcounter:  #2},#1%  
  borderline north={1.5pt}{14.4pt}{gray!50},
}
```

However, somehow I get this text below my listings for some reason:
[image: Image with extra text]

Does anyone know how to solve this, so I don't have the "keywordstyle keywordstyle" added?

I have been trying to solve this for some time now without any luck.

Comment: presumably from `moredelim={[is][keywordstyle]{@}{@}},`  but please provide an example that produces the output shown so people can debug

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. the optional argument `#1` should be at the end of the `newtcblisting` declaration, i.e.,

```
title={Listing \thetcbcounter:  #2}, 
  borderline north={1.5pt}{14.4pt}{gray!50},
  #1%
}
```

2. there is a comma missing between `escapeinside={\¤}{)}` and `keywordstyle=\color{blue},` which causes the word `keywordstyle` to be printed.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable, skins}
\newtcblisting[auto counter, list inside=codes]{pythonCode}[2][]{%
  listing only,
  breakable,
  top=0.25pt,
  bottom=0.25pt,
  right=0.25pt,
  left=0.25pt,
  colback=gray!15!white,
  colframe=gray!50,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  bottomrule=0pt,
  toprule=1.5pt,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  listing options={ %
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    moredelim={[is][keywordstyle]{@}{@}},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{darkgray},
    breaklines=false,
    breakautoindent=false,
    breakindent=0pt,
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    aboveskip=0pt,
    showtabs=false,
    belowskip=0pt,
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color
    escapechar=¤,
    escapeinside={\¤}{)},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
    stringstyle=\color{red},     % string literal style
    commentstyle=\color{green},    % comment style
  },%
  lefttitle=0pt,
  coltitle=black,
  colbacktitle=white,
  title={Listing \thetcbcounter:  #2}, 
  borderline north={1.5pt}{14.4pt}{gray!50},
  #1%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pythonCode}{Basic List Operations}
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>>
#index()
\end{pythonCode}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Frederik please provide the full MWE yourself next time, so we don't have to guess which `tcbuselibrary` statements are needed, how your colors are defined etc.

Comment: Hi @Marijn, I will do next time - and thank you for the help! Somehow I didn't get a notification that you had provided an answer, however, I really appreciate it!